# How to move all files and folders into a subfolder of the same folder

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab-ci

in the gitlab-ci for our automatic deployment pipeline, we need to move all files and folders of the old application into a folder "_backup" in the same root directory.

This is the folder:
[image]

This is our approach:
`mv /mnt/test.local/* /mnt/test.local/_backup`

But the error messages are:
`mv: can't rename '/mnt/test.local/favicon.ico': No such file or directory`

I think the problem is that I can not move all files and folders (including "_backup"-folder) into the "_backup"-folder. I read about the `extglob` shell options, but `!(_backup)` is not working, is there another way?

**Update**:
I tried @Kent's approach, but somehow it is not working. When I test it locally I get the following error but it works:

```
$ find ~/Workspace/testingmove/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -path ~/Workspace/testingmove/_backup -prune -o -print|xargs -I{} mv {} -t ~/Workspace/testingmove/_backup
mv: rename /Users/wiesenberg/Workspace/testingmove//_backup to /Users/wiesenberg/Workspace/testingmove/_backup/_backup: Invalid argument
mv: rename -t to /Users/wiesenberg/Workspace/testingmove/_backup/-t: No such file or directory
```

And when I try it in the gitlab-ci, the following error accurs:

```
$ find /mnt/test.local/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -path /mnt/test.local/_backup -prune -o -print|xargs -I{} mv {} -t /mnt/test.local/_backup/
 mv: unrecognized option: t
 BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.
 Usage: mv [-fin] SOURCE DEST
 or: mv [-fin] SOURCE... DIRECTORY
```

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Can you do a `ls -lrth /mnt/test.local/` and post the contents?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the folder to the description.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` to exclude the backup directory:

```
find /YourHome -mindepth 1 -path /YourHome/_backup -prune -o -print|xargs -I{} cp -r {} /YourHome/_backup
```

Replace the `cp` command in xargs with `mv` if you want to do "mv"

### update

```
find /YourHome -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -path /YourHome/_backup -prune -o -print|xargs -I{} mv {} -t /YourHome/_backup
```

Comment: I tried it and I think the problem is, that it will create a file "_backup" not a folder:
`$ find /mnt/test.local/* -mindepth 1 -path /mnt/test.local/_backup -prune -o -print|xargs -I{} mv {} /mnt/test.local/_backup`
Error: `mv: can't rename '/mnt/test.local/static/media': Not a directory`

Comment: @Wiesenberg remove the `*` and read the `mv` man page, particularly the `-t` option.

Comment: Sorry but `$ find /mnt/test.local/ -mindepth 1 -path /mnt/test.local/_backup -prune -o -print|xargs -I{} mv {} -t /mnt/test.local/_backup`is not working, I don't get it.

Comment: @Wiesenberg oh, I checked the command again, there was a problem, the max depth should be 1 as well. sorry my bad. pls try the updated answer

Comment: Please look at my question I added an UPDATE to show the results of my try. Thanks

Comment: It's your "mv" problem. perhaps the mv in busybox is not from GNU Coreutil. Pls read the man page (or try the suggestion in the error msg), do some test. @Wiesenberg

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is that I created a two subfolders and routed the Webserver to the subfolder.

```
- root
  - _backup
  - website
```